# Equations with conditional connectors

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

I am trying to calculate a pressure difference between two connectors, but one of them is conditional to a parameter calc_dp. The dp is only to be calculated if the calc_dp is true.

I tried something like this:

```
equation

if calc_dp then

  inlet.p - outlet.p = dp;

else

  dp = 0;

end if;
```

This doesn't work and i get an error saying that part of the equation is missing due to removal of connectors.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is, that port `outlet` may be conditionally present or not. In case that `outlet` is present, the equations should be good. Otherwise, the variable `outlet.p` does not exist, as `outlet` is not instantiated.

The following workaround is actually taken from `Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Interfaces.ConditionalHeatPort`:

```
package ConditionalPort

  connector Port
    Modelica.SIunits.Pressure p "Pressure";
  end Port;

  model ConditionalTwoPort
    parameter Boolean useOutlet = false "Enable outlet, if true";
    Port inlet "Port" annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-110,-10},{-90,10}})));
    Port outlet(p=pOutlet) if useOutlet "Conditional port" annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{90,-10},{110,10}})));
    Modelica.SIunits.Pressure dp "Pressure difference";
    Modelica.SIunits.Pressure pOutlet "Pressure of conditional port, if present";
  equation 
    if not useOutlet then
      pOutlet = 0;
    end if;
    dp = inlet.p - pOutlet;
  end ConditionalTwoPort;
end ConditionalPort;
```

One more note: Since Modelica models are not causal, it is very much recommended to use `port_a` and `port_b` instead of `inlet` and `outlet`.